# Looping in Angular 2

Tags: angular

whether angular 2 can perform its function in the loop?

i have code :

```
    setValueToForms(value) : void {
    if(value.length > 0){
        if(this.validationDataInput(value)== true){
            this.rows = value[0];
            if(this.rows['id']){
                this.id = this.rows['id'];
            }
            this.form.setValue({
                'id': this.id,
                'name': this.rows['name'],
                'description': this.rows['description'],
                'category': this.rows['category']
            });
            this.selectedRolesOld = value[0]['rolesList'];
            this.selectedRoles = this.selectedRolesOld;
            console.log(this.selectedRolesOld);
            this.statusForm = 'Edit';
        }
    }
    else{
        this.statusForm = 'Add';
    }
}
```

i want to loop this.selectedRoles, can anyone give me a clue about that ?

Comment: Don't quite understand what you're asking when you say "I want to loop this.selectedRoles. I'm assuming you're asking more than just how to use `[].forEach()`.

Comment: yes, just like what you say, i want to ask about forEach, can u give me example to use that ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To loop through items in array you can the newer `[].forEach` syntax as follows:

```
// assuming this.selectedRoles is an array
this.selectedRoles.forEach((_role) => {  
  // Do whatever test/work you need  
  if (_role === somethingToCompare) {  
    //...  
  }  
});
```

Or you can use a standard `for` loop:

```
// assuming this.selectedRoles is an array
for (let i = 0; i < this.selectedRoles.length; i++) {
  // Do whatever test/work you need  
  if (this.selectedRoles[i] === somethingToCompare) {  
    //...  
  }  
}
```

Note: Untested code written on an iPad. :)

Comment: Is this what you're looking for?

Answer (score 0):

You can also do with for loop. Below code is written in typescript.

```
for (let i = 0; i < this.array.length; i++) {
   // write your code here
}
```